# Unable to rank / row number for a dataset in Teradata

Tags: teradata, rank, row-number

I have a dataset in teradata table with the following fields

[image]

i would like to rank or row number to aggregate further analysis
based on the field : sales plan when it is changed.

Unable to rank them proper depends on the change, i tried group by, rank and dense rank but not yielding the proper results

i got the result set like below:

[image]

but the expecting results

[image]

how to get the expected results?

Comment: Is this your final result or do you want some additional calculations on top of it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of *gaps & islands* problem, you need to caculate a 0/1 flag that is set to 1 whenever the sales_plan changes compared to the previous row. Then you do a Cumulative Sum over this flag to get the "rank":

```
with cte as 
 (
   select ...
      case when sales_plan = lag(sales_plan, 1, sales_plan)
                             over (partition by order_prod_id 
                                   order by sales_date) 
           then 0 
           else 1
      end as flag
   from my_table
)
select ...
   sum(flag) over (partition by order_prod_id 
                   rows unbounded preceding
                   order by sales_date) + 1 as rnk
from cte
```

Comment: @dneoth , Thanks alot for your help, I have tried this sql but i got the same rank for all the rows . i'm doing something wrong in the sql please suggest

Comment: Sorry , I forgot adding "rows unbounded preceding"